# Terms of use button in installation not responding for 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, ce-1.9.2.1, terms-and-conditions

I wanted to install a fresh Magento so:

After copying gzip 1.9.2.1 full installation to ftp folder, I changed the premissions for all files in root magento folder /shop/ to 644.
After going to the address, installation page shows with terms of use and after marking the check mark I wanted to click continue, but it doesn't respond.

Can't install Magento on a same server where 1.9.0 and 1.4 were installed.

Comment: Your magento installation is missing JS libraries, try replacing JS folder from a fresh Magento.

Comment: Or you still have permissions issues on those JS files

Comment: Yes, it was permissions, I had to manually change permisions for following files:  /js/prototype/validation.js, /js/scriptaculous/effects.js and /js/prototype/prototype.js

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in permissions, after manually changing permisions for following files: 
/js/prototype/validation.js
/js/scriptaculous/effects.js
/js/prototype/prototype.js

All started to work as it should.